# JavaScript slide stay on the same slide after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-slides

I have a JavaScript slide, inside of it is a gridview. I want to stay on the same slide after the postback or page refresh. The gridview both have different functions.

This is my code.

Html:

```
<div class = "callbacks_container">
    <div class="rslides callbacks callbacks1" id="slider3">

        <div class = "grid-slide">
            <div class = "prg-dte">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" class = "srch-res" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div class = "table-grid">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class = "grd-view table table-hover table-striped" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div class = "grid-slide">
            <div class = "prg-dte">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" class = "srch-res" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div class = "table-grid">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" class = "grd-view table table-hover table-striped" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview2_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        nav: true,
        speed: 500,
        namespace: "callbacks",
        before: function() {
            $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
        },
        after: function() {
            $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided responsiveSlides lets you get and set the current slide, you would use a cookie to memorize the current slide, and read from that cookie each time the page loads.

This answer shows you how to get the current slide: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23815701/2413794

Comment: Sorry I am just a newbie in JavaScript. Is that okay if I ask for a sample code related to my concern? Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I want to see you trying, not copy-pasting.

Comment: I did trying and not copy pasting, but unfortunately its not working. That is way I'm asking you.